# Hex more than 0x80, is received as c2 80 in TCP Server when sent from android applicaton

Tags: android, utf-8, tcp, hex

I am trying to build an android application where in I send data to the TCP Server and if the correct data is received on the server, it responds back.

The problem is here :
I am sending

```
char[] charArray= {0x05, 0x03, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x04,0x45,0x8D};
```

And it is received by TCP server as given below :

```
{05}{03}{00}{03}{00}{04}{45}{C2}{8D}
```

This extra "C2" is creating the problem due to which I am not able the communicate with the TCP server.

I have searched a lot. And I have got the problem that in "UTF-8" encoding Hex above "7F" will have "C2" attached with it. For ex : "C280".

I want to get rid of this "C2". If there is some other thing which is causing this problem, please give me the solution.

Please refer the below code :

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
private static TextView textResponse;
private EditText editTextAddress, editTextPort;
private Button buttonConnect;
private String message = "Hi client!";
private static String kq = "";
private ClientTask myClientTask;
private OnListener listener;
private static boolean flag = true;
Socket socket = null;

public interface OnListener {
    void listener(String text);
}

public void addListener(OnListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

static Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if (flag) {
            kq += msg.obj.toString() + "\r\n";
            textResponse.setText(kq);
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editTextAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address);
    editTextPort = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.port);
    buttonConnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect);
    textResponse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.response);

    buttonConnect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myClientTask = new ClientTask(editTextAddress.getText()
                    .toString(), Integer.parseInt(editTextPort.getText()
                    .toString()));
            myClientTask.execute();
        }
    });

}

public class ClientTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> implements
        OnListener {

    String dstAddress;
    int dstPort;
    PrintWriter out1;


    ClientTask(String addr, int port) {
        dstAddress = addr;
        dstPort = port;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);
            out1 = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            out1.flush();

            BufferedReader in1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    socket.getInputStream()));
            do {
                try {
                    if (!in1.ready()) {
                        if (message != null) {
                            MainActivity.handler.obtainMessage(0, 0, -1,"Server : " + message).sendToTarget();
                            message = "";
                        }
                    }
                    int num = in1.read();
                    message += Character.toString((char) num);
                } catch (Exception classNot) {
                }
            } while (!message.equals("bye")); 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try {
            if (socket.isClosed()) {
                flag = false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Socket Exception", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    public void listener(String text) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        sendMessage(text);
    }

    void sendMessage(String msg) {
        try { 
            out1.print(msg);
            out1.flush();
            if (!msg.equals("bye"))
                MainActivity.handler.obtainMessage(0, 0, -1, "Me: " + msg)
                        .sendToTarget();
            else
                MainActivity.handler.obtainMessage(0, 0, -1,
                        "Exception Not Handled").sendToTarget();
        } catch (Exception ioException) {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void send(View v) {
    addListener(myClientTask);
    if (listener != null) {
        byte[] charArray= {0x05,0x03,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x08,0x45,0x8D};
        String newString1 = new String(charArray);
            listener.listener(newString1);            
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        if (listener != null)
            listener.listener("bye");
        socket.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        if (listener != null)
            listener.listener("bye");
        socket.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    super.onStop();
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

}

Comment: You should do two things: Show code that sends the data. Show code that receives the data.

Comment: 'char[] charArray'. Do not use 'char'. Change to 'byte'.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If I change the char array to byte array, it gives error on "0x8D". So, I can't use byte array for extended ASCII characters

Comment: What kind of error exactly? And show the statement please.

Comment: You are talking nonsence as a byte is 8 bits and can hold values up to 0xFF. Yours are smaller.

Comment: @user3793037: "*So, I can't use byte array for extended ASCII characters*" - yes, you most certainly CAN. And FYI, `0xB5` is ALSO extended ASCII (anything between 0x80-0xFF, inclusive, is extended ASCII, more commonly referred to as ANSI). If you are encountering a compiler error, you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @greenapps : I think I am not talking nonsense. If you read the basics again, byte is from -128 to 127. And if we convert 127 to hex, then the conversion comes to 7F.

Comment: @RemyLebeau : Actually B5 was just a typing mistake. It was 45. I have attached the full code.

Comment: Nonsense. You can consider the values of a byte as signed integer or as unsigned integer. At your wish. And the values are always from 0x00-0xFF. So you are doing something wrong interpreting your bytes.

Answer (score 1):

```
char[] charArray= {0x05, 0x03, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x04,0x45,0x8D};
```

`char` is for characters. Use `byte[]`:

```
byte[] byteArray= {0x05, 0x03, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x04,0x45,(byte)0x8D};
```